# Reconfiguring an IR detector circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design

I found this simple little IR detector circuit that seems to fit my needs, but it would be more useful if the output went high when the beam is interrupted instead of high when the beam is detected.

Would achieving that be as simple as flipping the connections of pins 2 and 3 on the LM358?

[image]

Comment: swapping R2 and photo diode should also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just swap the connections of pins 2, 3 of LM358